# Finding exact solutions to $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + x\right) $

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the exact solutions to $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - x\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + x\right) $$

It says to solve for exact values algebraically but I'm not sure where to start. I've been trying different ways but nothing makes sense.

Comment: So what did you try so far? What was your very first approach?

Comment: Solutions to what ? Should the minus sign be an equal sign or is an $=0$ missing ?

Comment: This is only an expression, not an equation. We can't find the solutions to $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3} - x\right) - \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6} - x\right)$. Are you trying to find its roots instead?

Comment: I expanded it into one of the identities but that lead nowhere

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj  It says to solve algebraically where 0≤x<2pi and to give answers as exact solutions

Comment: You are still not able to provide an equation. You solve an equation : a = b. There must be an equality sign somewhere, you understand ?

Comment: This is not an equation. Did you mean to set this difference equal to zero, or what exactly?

Comment: I think OP probably doesn't want to find the zeros of this expression, as any real number satisfies it, as someone's observed in one of the answers below. I think they might have miscopied the minus symbol for an equality symbol.

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is identically $0$. The first term is $\cos (\frac {\pi} 2- (\frac {\pi} 3 -x))=\cos (\frac {\pi} 6+x)$

Comment: Great observation!

Answer (score 1):

**$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+x\right)=0$$**

We have, $\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+x\right)$=$=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\sin \left(x\right)$

(Simplifying): $\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\sin \left(x\right)$

$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\sin \left(x\right)$

$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)$

Also, $\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)$=$=-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right)\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right)$

$=-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right)\cos \left(x\right)$

$=-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)$

Therefore, 
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)=0$$

Now, $-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)$

$=-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)$

As, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos \left(x\right)$ $=\cos \left(x\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$

And $-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(x\right)$ $=\sin \left(x\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ $=-\sin \left(x\right)$

So we have equation as $$-\sin \left(x\right)+\sqrt{3}\cos \left(x\right)=0$$

$\frac{-\sin \left(x\right)+\sqrt{3}\cos \left(x\right)}{\cos \left(x\right)}=\frac{0}{\cos \left(x\right)}$

$\sqrt{3}-\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{\cos \left(x\right)}=0$

$\sqrt{3}-\tan \left(x\right)=0$

$\tan \left(x\right)=\sqrt{3}$

$$x=\frac{\pi }{3}+\pi n$$

Comment: The OP's expression *subtracts* the cosine from the sine; your opening equation *adds* it.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Thankyou for that. I missed that one. I'll correct it.

Comment: If this is indeed the equation OP wants to solve, then as Kavi Rama Murthy has observed, any real $x$ satisfies it.

Comment: @Allawonder if you'll look closely I've made mistake in taking the given equation (I have taken + in between). And yes he is correct.